# KMS - all clients remain in "Initial Grace Period"

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, kms, licensing

I've set up KMS on a Server 2008 R2 Datacenter machine and all looks pretty good. The proper DNS entry got added and Windows 7 clients are listed on the server. They have all stayed in the "Initial Grace Period" part though.

Is that normal, and if not how do I go about resolving it?

Thanks.

---

Update 20111808

So, here is part of the /dli information on the KMS server:

```
    License Status: Licensed

Key Management Service is enabled on this machine
    Current count: 50
    Listening on Port: 1688
    DNS publishing enabled
    KMS priority: Normal

Key Management Service cumulative requests received from clients
    Total requests received: 213
    Failed requests received: 0
    Requests with License Status Unlicensed: 0
    Requests with License Status Licensed: 2
    Requests with License Status Initial grace period: 203
    Requests with License Status License expired or Hardware out of tolerance: 0

    Requests with License Status Non-genuine grace period: 0
    Requests with License Status Notification: 8
```

So apparently the Current Count of 50 can never get higher as only the last 50 requests are cached. That is a good sign, but I can't find anywhere if the 203 in Initial grace period is normal and where should they eventually end up? In the "Requests with License Status Licensed:" I'd presume.

Again any information gratefully received.

Cheers.

Comment: did you install your license for kms correctly?

Comment: I can only imagine that I did, but all the commands completed successfully (The /ipk and /ato commands)

Comment: How many Windows 7 clients do you have? More than 25?

Comment: Yep, over 100 in there. I started this thread many days ago and the clients are still in Initial Grace Period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well according to Microsoft this is completely normal and the machines will end up in "Licensed" when the Grace period of 30 days is up.
Got to say I'm a little suspicious about that, but I have to take their word for it. I'll update this post again in a few weeks if that does not turn out to be the case.

UPDATE:
I can now confirm that the machines have moved into "Licensed". It didn't take the full 30 days, but something like two weeks instead.

Comment: I think the stats are listing the status of the client when it made the request. So when a newly installed client makes it's first request it will have been in status "initial grace period", when it checks in later to renew it's activation (kms activations are time limited) it will have been in status "licensed".

Answer (score 0):

For now you can see the activation status of your machines using the graphical [Volume Activation Management Tool (VAMT) 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11936) and from the tool you can force the inmediate activation towards the KMS Server.

Comment: The clients are already activated, and the KMS Host is activated too - it's just that everything is shown in the initial grace section. No device on the network even mentions being in grace in it's own properties. It's like the KMS Host is just reporting things incorrectly. Thanks